# Sampling points from a space defined by bounded inequality

Tags: sampling, simplex

I have the problem: I'd like to generate a uniform sampling of points from a space defined by the bounded constraints and linear inequality described below:
$$lb_1 \leq x_1 \leq ub_1$$
$$lb_2 \leq x_2 \leq ub_2$$
$$lb_3 \leq x_1 + x_2 \leq ub_3$$
With two variables and the linear inequality, this results in a 2D surface from which I'd like to sample 50 points uniformly distributed across the surface.

Take the example where $5 \leq x1 \leq 10$, $4 \leq x2 \leq 8$, and $10 \leq x_1 + x_2 \leq 12$. This surface looks like a rhombus. It is easy to create a span of values across $x_1$ {5.0, 5.1, …, 10.0}, then for each point solve for the values of $x_2$ which satisfy the inequality.  Is there another way to approach this?

I see similar questions about [uniformly sampling points within a cube](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1525249/uniformly-sampling-points-from-inside-a-region-of-cube) or [sampling of points on a simplex](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/502583/uniform-sampling-of-points-on-a-simplex?noredirect=1&lq=1) which seem similar to this question. In both of those questions, the solution seemed to be creating a Dirichlet distribution and sampling points from that distribution.

Can this problem be solved through uniformly sampling points on a simplex represented as a Dirichlet distribution?