# Finding a mapping from the hypercube to a convex hull that conserves the uniform distribution

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, sampling, simplex

I am drawing points uniformly in a hypercube $x \in [-1,1]^n$ and I would like to find a map f(x) = y such that $||y||_1 \leq 1$ and that the uniform distribution is conserved.

My own attempt at this basically rescales the vector x, to the appropriate length, but preserves the direction.

$y = \frac{||x||_\infty}{||x||_1} x$

Written in python it looks like this:

```
def hypercube_to_simplex(x):
    c = np.max(np.abs(x),axis=1) / np.linalg.norm(x, ord=1,axis=1)
    y = c[:,None] * x
    return y

X = np.random.rand(30000,2)*2-1
plt.scatter(X[:,0],X[:,1],s=1)
Y = hypercube_to_simplex(X)
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(Y[:,0],Y[:,1],s=1)
```

The problem with my method is that it does not preserve the uniform distribution as seen by the scatter plots:

[image: Uniform distribution in hypercube space]
[image: Non uniform distribution]

To me it looks like I need to skew the distribution of each individual $x_i$, but I can't quite grasp how.
I know this question is related to previous questions asked like: [Uniform sampling of points on a simplex](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/502583/uniform-sampling-of-points-on-a-simplex)
but I can't figure out how to apply the solutions from there to my problem.