# Random points inside a convex polytope

Tags: convex-analysis, random, sampling, conformal-geometry

Given a convex polytope, defined by set of vertices $P = \{\mathbf{x}^{(i)}\}_{i = 1}^n, x^{(i)} = (x^{(i)}_1, x^{(i)}_2, \dots, x^{(i)}_d): \operatorname{conv}(P) = P$.

How to generate uniformely distributed points inside a convex polytope without rejection operation (i.e. "inline")?

I know only the solution of simpliest connected problem in $d$-dimensional space: [sampling uniformly at random from a $d - 1$-dimensional unit simplex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010837/sample-uniformly-at-random-from-an-n-dimensional-unit-simplex/3080946#3080946). To perform such sampling inline, there need only the $d$ uniformely distributed random values for each **d**-dimensional point of $d - 1$-simplex. So, there is some kind of projection (transformation) of ${(\operatorname{uniform}[0;1])}^d$ (hypercube, consist of $d$ uniformely distributed values) onto $\sum\limits_{j = 1}^dx_j=1$ plane.

Internals of a convex polytope can be expressed as $V = \{\mathbf{x}^{(0)} \;|\; x_j^{(0)} = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n c_j^{(i)} \cdot x_j^{(i)}, c_j^{(i)} \in [0;1], \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n c_j^{(i)} = 1\}$, but how to infer the form of distribution of random numbers $c_j^{(i)}$ is the issue. I suspect, that the form is (maybe some generalization) of *Gamma distribution*, but how to infer the parametres -- I don't know.

**EDIT:**

[This question is duplicate. I answered a similar question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/871220/54348)

Answer (score 1):

If you can afford prior decomposition of the polytope into symplexes then choose a random symplex with probability distribution corresponding to symplexes' (hyper)volumes, then choose a point randomly within a symplex. Will work also for concave and not connected polytopes (sets of polytopes).

Comment: OK, triangulation is obvious step. But what to do with individual simplixes? I think, that mapping of standard unit simplex to arbitrary simplex is the task close to normal transformations problem (every volume element suffers defformation, and inverse function of its spatial distribution is what I need, if I understand right).